# Git Extensions not showing the same folder/submodules after cloning a repo than using Git on command line

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-extensions

I'm not really sure what's happening. I cloned a Gitlab repository and when I see the folders/submodules in the command line it matches what is on my remote repo.

Remote Gitlab going into model_target folder, it has csar_lib:
[image]

Git on command line, in model_target folder:

[image]

But when using Git Extensions, model_target folder:
[image]

It's showing csar_utilities instead of csar_lib.

They're all pointing at the same commit ID, that's why it's a bit strange to see the difference.

Comment: This is not a representation of your filesystem, this is a representation of what's in .gitmodules file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should mean in command line, you use a [`git clone -recurse-submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---recurse-submodulesltpathspecgt), which cloned the parent repository and its submodule.

But the [Submodule view of Git Extension](https://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/release-3.4/submodules.html) only lists submodules root tree.

The latest [Git Extension release 4.0.0](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/blob/a947e095b4a4b63c3edd5d9dd8038b26813a706f/GitUI/Resources/ChangeLog.md#version-400-31-oct-2022) does include a [PR 10145: Open new instance if double click on current submodule](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/pull/10145):

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6248932/184008972-b8594da3-7e49-4510-bf05-1de2702b6bbb.png]